# Boot Weblogic Server with the flag -server before or after of the memory definition

Tags: java, performance, weblogic

I'm trying find a explanation about the usage of **-server** flag in the Weblogic Server start.

I don't find any documentation about if the **-server** should or if it is mandatory be the first argument of the Java Options.

*Example:*

**java -server -Xms256m -Xmx512m**

*OR*

**java -Dweblogic.ProductionModeEnabled=true -server -Xms256m -Xmx512m**

I'm sorry for the question but I have this question without a **concrete** answer.

Comment: The `-server` is a command line option to `java`, and is probably the default with your JRE.

Answer (score 1):

For your scenario, it does not matter. It needs to be before "`-jar filename`" and any *arguments*. `-server` is an option, so just goes anywhere in the list of options which should appear before "`-jar filename`", as [the documentation states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html), the format is:

> **java** [options] classname [args]
>   **java** [options] **-jar** filename [args]

It should also be noted that the `-server` option is default in 64-bit (OpenJDK based) JVMs. This quote is from the same page:

> **-server**
>   Selects the Java HotSpot Server VM. The 64-bit version of the JDK supports only the Server VM, so in that case the option is
>   implicit.
>
> For default JVM selection, see Server-Class Machine Detection at
>   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html